# How to align ImageButton(s) and Buttons in same action bar?

Tags: android, button

I have a simple action bar, It contains two `ImageButton`s and and a `Button`. The problem is The images in `ImageButton`s are not exactly in the centre of the bar. Without the `Button`, They seem to aligned because the action bar itself  wraps perfectly around them. But when I introduce a `Button` the `ImageButton`s seem to stick to the ceiling of the bar.
Here is my .xml file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0099cc"
tools:context="com.convo.imgfs.FullscreenActivity">


<!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
     is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
     TextureView, etc. -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_image"
    android:scaleType = "centerCrop"/>
<!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
     android:fitsSystemWindows. -->
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
        style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/likes_button"
            android:src="@drawable/likes_imgbutton"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/comments_button"
            android:src="@drawable/comments_imgbutton"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            style="?metaButtonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:text="37 comments"
            android:id="@+id/show_comments_button"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Done"
        android:id="@+id/done_button"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And here is a [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkCCm.jpg) of the activity (The 'Likes' and 'Comments' icons should be horizontally aligned with the the text "37 comments")

Comment: Why at-least 10 rep is needed for posting images?

Answer (score 0):

Use gravity in this imageButton tags as per my understanding your xml code is perfect for your requirement just you need to give **gravity to it  as centerVetical**

```
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/comments_button"
            android:src="@drawable/comments_imgbutton"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Comment: When I tried your solution for anyone of the `ImageButton`s, it seemes working, but when I tried aligning both of them [result](http://imgur.com/NWSjcNr) was rather weird.

Comment: then i think you need to use    android:layout_height="match_parent" in both image view cause anyways your giving source as a input to imageButton hope so above line will work just try it

Comment: android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: That had no effect. The icons remain congested.

Comment: :( oopppppppppppppppsssssss